Young measure generated by the sequence $\sin(2\pi nt)$
I consider the sequence $x_n(t)=\sin(2\pi nt)$ for $t\in[a,b]$. Clearly this sequence is not convergent in the usual sense but is it bounded, by the fundamental theorem on Young measures, there exists a mapping $\mu$ such that for all $t\in[a,b]$, $\mu_t$ is a probability measure on $[-1,1]$ satisfying
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{a}^{b}f(x_n(t))dt = \int_{a}^{b}\left(\int_{-1}^{1}f(x)\mu_t(dx)\right)dt
$$
For all test function $f\in C([-1,1]$.
I want to find explicitly the mapping $\mu_t$ but I have some difficulty in doing so. Here is my attempt :
I first decided to consider the arcsine function to get
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{a}^{b}2\pi ntdt = \int_{a}^{b}\left(\int_{-1}^{1}\arcsin(x)\mu_t(dx)\right)dt
$$
But this is not helpful. I would like to know what can I do in this situation so do not hesitate to give me some hints (instead of full answers please).
Thank you a lot !
